# Pandas multiplying column values under condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

would appreciate help with this:
I have clean float value in column (pandas DF), if this value is <1 (bad parsed data), i need to multiply it with Price value from another column (corresponding axis).

```
    Price    Comission
    10 000   0.1 
    50 000   5 000 
    75 000   0.5
```

I tried smth like this : (without succes)

```
for i in range (df.shape [0]): 
  if (df['Comission'].iloc(i)<1)&(df['Comission'].iloc(i)>0):
    df['Comission'].iloc(i)= df['Comission'].iloc(i)*df['Price'].iloc(i)
```

Is there a way to do the selection easier in Pandas and multiply under selection?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"price": [10, 50, 75], "commision": [0.1, 5.0, 0.5]})
print(df)

==>
   price  commision
0     10        0.1
1     50        5.0
2     75        0.5


df.loc[df.commision < 1, "commision"] = df.commision * df.price
print(df)

==>
   price  commision
0     10        1.0
1     50        5.0
2     75       37.5
```

Comment: `df['commision'] * df['price']` will work, dont need the `loc` command after assignment :)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I tried that - =having problem in multiplication - since 2 columns are float can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: not sure I follow. Are you getting some kind of error? What's the issue, exactly?

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
     92         if mask.any():
     93             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
---> 94                 result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
     95 
     96     else:
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Could you please run df.to_dict(), and add the results to the question? It seems like your data is different than mine.

Comment: I am working in Colab, sorry I am new here - dont' know how to do this. I can link the notebook. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ff324pMQ9X4lqFV_tjLfe7Y10LDX2OdQ?usp=sharing

Comment: just do "df.to_dict()" and copy&paste the output.

Comment: "df.to_dict()"1280: 8700000.0,
  1282: 6630000.0,
  1284: 5300000.0,
  1286: 5800000.0,
  1288: 8800000.0,
  1290: 9500000.0,
  1292: 7500000.0,
  1294: 6480000.0,
  1296: 11500000.0,
  1298: 5700000.0,
  1300: 6500000.0,
  1302: 17000000.0,
  1304: 5150000.0,
  1306: 7650000.0,
  1308: 7200000.0,
  1310: 7700000.0,
  1312: 5000000.0,
  1314: 5600000.0,
  1316: 5550000.0,
  1318: 8400000.0,
  1320: 8500000.0,
  1322: 5990000.0,
  1324: 11800000.0,
   ...}}
  It is too long to paste here

Comment: Sorry - I couldn't extract anything meaningful from this partial copy&paste. Let's try something different: can to do df.head(5).to_dict(), and paste the results here?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Roy2012's answer (+1), here's another way to do it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Price": [10, 50, 75], "Commision": [0.1, 5.0, 0.5]})

df['Price'] = np.where(
    df['Price'] < 1,                # Condition (price < 1).
    df['Price'] * df['Comission'],  # What to assign to price when condition is true. 
    df['Price']                     # What to assign to price when condition is false.
)
```

Comment: hello Victor, thannks for reply. I tried your np.where - I can't understand why it is not going to compare. Both columns are converted to float.         df['Бонус агенту']= np.where(df['Бонус агенту']<1,df['Бонус агенту']*df['Цена, руб.']/100, df['Бонус агенту']) - eror <=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'